# Handling form data with flask request

Tags: python, flask, axios

I am using `flask-restful` as an api server and am constructing the first `PUT` method.  Using request imported from flask, I am able to access `request.form` data without issue with the following cURL command:

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/v1/system/account -X PUT -d username=asdas -d email=asdasd@test.com
```

My `PUT` method logs out both the username and email without issue:

```
def put(self):
    print 'SystemAccountPut'
    print request.form['username']
    print request.form['email']
    return
```

Output:

```
SystemAccountPut
asdas
asdasd@test.com
```

I have an app using the [axios project](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios) to make api calls.  When axios attempts to `PUT` form data, `request.form` no longer works.  Here is the call axios is making converted to cURL command from Chrome Dev Console:

```
curl 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/v1/system/account' -X PUT -H 'Pragma: no-cache' -H 'Origin: http://127.0.0.1:5000' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.116 Safari/537.36' -H 'Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8' -H 'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*' -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' -H 'Referer: http://127.0.0.1:5000/settings' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' --data-binary '{"username":"asdas","email":"asdasd@test.com"}' --compressed
```

With the same method above `request.form['username']` and `request.form['email']` are empty.  `request.data` however has the form data in it, and `request.get_json()` also will output the form data in JSON format.

My question is what should I be using in this case to retrieve the form data? The first curl command is clean with `request.form` having the data I need, but `request.data` is empty.  The second cURL command leaves `request.form` broken but does populate `request.data`.  Is there a best practice on how I should retrieve form data in both cURL cases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out the issue after further learning more about incoming forms and some insight from davidism.  The first cURL example has the following Content-Type: `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.  The second cURL command has the following Content-Type: `application/json;charset=UTF-8`.  Unsurprisingly, the first cURL command sends form data to `request.form` and the second cURL command is interpreted as data and can retrieved at `request.data` or `request.get_json()`.  For my needs I want to get the form data either way, so in my `put` method I have the following:

```
    data = request.get_json() or request.form
    print data['email']
    print data['username']
```

This gives me the email and password in both cURL examples.